# Как запустить анимацию на определенное время?

Tags: javascript, анимация

У меня есть главный цикл программы, зацикленный с помощью requestAnimationFrame
Как к примеру после того как персонаж врезался отключить для него коллизию на 3 секунды и мигать с одной скоростью?
При этом весь игровой процесс будет продолжать анимироваться с другой скоростью

Как во время одной анимации запустить другую с другой скоростью и на время?

Код я думаю тут не требуется, стандартный цикл анимации с помощью requestAnimationFrame:

```
function loop() {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)

    let now = new Date().getTime(),
        dt = now - (time || now)

    time = now

    game.step(dt)
    game.render()
}
```

Comment: использовать таймер? setTimeout

Comment: Да,  я понимаю что с их помощью надо делать. Но как? И без них можно обойтись?

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(loop,1000)
setInterval(loop,1000)
```

выбирай один из них

Comment: Как будто они одинаковые. Вводите в заблуждение новичков.

Comment: Да какой я новичок, я прекрасно знаю что это за функции и что для анимации их лучше не использовать. при чем тут вообще setInterval? Я спросил как на какое то время запустить анимацию, чтоб она выключилась через 3 скажем секунды